# pyparsing OneOrMore's embedded within other OneOrMore's

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, pyparsing

I am trying to use **pyparsing** for the first time.
My parser is not doing what I hope it would do, could someone please check and see what is wrong. **I am trying to embedd OneOrMore within OneOrMore, which I think should work fine but it is not.**

below is the whole code:

```
import pyparsing

status = """
    sale number       : 11/7 
    NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
    cross-cu-1       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
    cross-cu-2        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
    sale number       : 11/8 
    NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
    cross-cu-3       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
    cross-cu-4        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
    """

integer = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums).setParseAction(lambda toks: int(toks[0]))
decimal = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums + ".").setParseAction(lambda toks: float(toks[0]))
wordSuppress = pyparsing.Suppress(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas))
endOfLine = pyparsing.LineEnd().suppress()
colon = pyparsing.Suppress(":")

saleNumber = pyparsing.Regex("\d{2}\/\d{1}").setResultsName("saleNumber")
lineSuppress = pyparsing.Regex("NAME.*STOP") + endOfLine
saleRow = wordSuppress + wordSuppress + colon + saleNumber + endOfLine

name = pyparsing.Regex("cross-cu-\d").setResultsName("name")
id = integer.setResultsName("id")
pawn = integer.setResultsName("pawn")
price = integer.setResultsName("price") + "K"
time = pyparsing.Regex("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}").setResultsName("time")
c = decimal.setResultsName("c") + "%"
state = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas).setResultsName("state")
startStop = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums).setResultsName("startStop")
row = name + id + pawn + price + time + c + state + startStop + endOfLine

table = pyparsing.OneOrMore(pyparsing.Group(saleRow + lineSuppress.suppress() + (pyparsing.OneOrMore(pyparsing.Group(row) | pyparsing.SkipTo(row).suppress())) ) | pyparsing.SkipTo(saleRow).suppress())

resultDic = [x.asDict() for x in table.parseString(status)]
print resultDic
```

**It returns only** `[{'saleNumber': '11/7'}]`
**I was hoping to get a list of dic like this:**

```
[{ {'saleNumber': '11/7'},{ elements in cross-cu-1 line, elements in cross-cu-2 line } },
 { {'saleNumber': '11/8'},{ elements in cross-cu-3 line, elements in cross-cu-4 line } }]
```

Any help is appreciated!
***Please don´t suggest other ways of implementing this output! I am trying to learn pyparsing as well!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case pyparsing is probably overkill. Why don't you simply read the file line by line and then parse the results?

The code would look like this:

EDIT: I have updated the code to follow your example more closely.

from collections import defaultdict

```
status = """
sale number       : 11/7
NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
cross-cu-1       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
cross-cu-2        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
sale number       : 11/8
NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
cross-cu-3       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
cross-cu-4        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
"""

sale_number = ''

sales = defaultdict(list)

for line in status.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("NAME"):
         continue
    elif line.startswith("sale number"):
         sale_number = line.split(':')[1].strip()
    elif not line or line.isspace() :
         continue
    else:
         # you can also use a regular expression here
         sales[sale_number].append(line.split())

for sale in sales:
    print sale, sales[sale]
```

Comment: this is just one small part of a larger application and since the other parts use pyparsing I am trying to use it too and keep it consistent.

Comment: I think in this case consistency is not worth the effort of trying to do this in pyparsing. I have edited by response to show what it would look like without pyparsing.

Comment: nice quote, however I don´t see the relevance in this case. Are you questioning pyparsing? and advocating parsing the file one line at a time? Really?

Comment: Yes really. I think my edited answer is clearer than the PyParsing example. However, in general I think that pyparsing and related parser tools are difficult to handle. I tend to need recipes that follow a worked example closely to get working results.

Comment: My apologies, I missed your last line that you also wanted to learn pyparsing. I have added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import pyparsing

status = """
sale number       : 11/7
NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
cross-cu-1       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
cross-cu-2        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
sale number       : 11/8
NAME               ID    PAWN    PRICE    TIME         %C     STATE     START/STOP
cross-cu-3       1055       1    106284K  07:49:36.19  25.05%   run          1d01h
cross-cu-4        918       1    104708K  07:38:19.08  24.02%   run          1d01h
"""

integer = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums).setParseAction(lambda toks: int(toks[0]))
decimal = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums + ".").setParseAction(lambda toks:     float(toks[0]))
wordSuppress = pyparsing.Suppress(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas))
endOfLine = pyparsing.LineEnd().suppress()
colon = pyparsing.Suppress(":")

saleNumber = pyparsing.Regex("\d{2}\/\d{1}").setResultsName("saleNumber")
lineSuppress = pyparsing.Regex("NAME.*STOP") + endOfLine
saleRow = wordSuppress + wordSuppress + colon + saleNumber + endOfLine

name = pyparsing.Regex("cross-cu-\d").setResultsName("name")
id = integer.setResultsName("id")
pawn = integer.setResultsName("pawn")
price = integer.setResultsName("price") + "K"
time = pyparsing.Regex("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}").setResultsName("time")
c = decimal.setResultsName("c") + "%"
state = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas).setResultsName("state")
startStop = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums).setResultsName("startStop")
row = pyparsing.Group(name + id + pawn + price + time + c + state + startStop +    endOfLine)
row.setResultsName("row")
rows = pyparsing.OneOrMore(row).setResultsName("rows")

table = pyparsing.OneOrMore(pyparsing.Group(saleRow + lineSuppress + rows))

resultDic = [x.asDict() for x in table.parseString(status)]
print resultDic
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is not working. It is somehow skipping cross-cu-1 and cross-cu-3

Comment: I have updated the solution. Now it no longer skips the first cross-cu-\d element. The resulting dictionary now contains a "rows" and "salesNumber" attributes. Since the row elements are all named, the resulting data structure is somewhat complex.